# abcpdf export to pdf on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, abcpdf, abcpdf9

I have an aspx page that brings up a simple invoice. I want to have a button to be able to click on to export to pdf. Is there a function in abcpdf that will allow me to export the current page to pdf?

Just for testing, i can read in an html file and output to pdf fine without any problems. I just want it to export the current http response as a pdf if possible?

Comment: Are you trying to save a web page (response) ?

Comment: yes, i want to be able to export the current page that i am on

Comment: any ideas on how to do this, or if its even possible?

Comment: Found this while googling not sure if it works with your solution http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-9.htm

Comment: Thanks, i tried that, but it doesn't show how to take the current page and export it to pdf, it shows how to put in a url of page and export that to pdf, which i've tested and works fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with **ITextSharp** open source library for this which will resolve your problem. Have you?